# Changing user in docker container changes bash settings

Tags: bash, docker, environment-variables

I'm experiencing this behavior:
I have a docker image:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
...

RUN useradd -m develop
USER develop
```

When I run the container:

```
docker run -it my_image
```

I get a terminal with all the features such as LS_COLORS, completion of files/directories names with TAB, etc. But if I run the container with root user:

```
docker run -it -u 0 my_image
```

And then, in the container:

```
~$ su develop
```

Now my prompt doesn't havae any of the above features, and is very hard to work with. Can someone explain this behavior? I assume it has something to do with all the initialization scripts such as .bashrc, /etc/profile, etc., but I don't quite understand the difference between the two above scenarios.

### EDIT

Thanks @ItayB for the answer, I just figured it out also :).

But still, the behavior is not exactly the same as if I would just login as develop:

```
~$ docker run -it -u 0 build_agent:0.5
root@6acf7b900da3:/# su develop
$ bash
To run a command as administrator (user "root"), use "sudo <command>".
See "man sudo_root" for details.

bash: /root/.bashrc: Permission denied
develop@6acf7b900da3:/$ cd ~
bash: cd: /root: Permission denied
develop@6acf7b900da3:/$
```

As you can see, the environment variables are still set as if I was "Root" user. Why is that?

Comment: su -p will preserve the environment but the issue you will have is that the user develop may not have access to /root/.bashrc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should explicitly call `bash` after switching user:

```
$ docker run -it -u 0 my_image
root@74765d85882a:/# su develop
$ bash
develop@74765d85882a:/$
```